# How to get CKEditor to save locally.

Tags: javascript, html, save, ckeditor

I've been looking for a Word Processor to put on a web OS I'm creating and CKEditor was the easiest out of all the ones I found on the internet to implement. (The OS runs in any of the major browsers).

The problem is, I looked all over the internet to see how to save anything put into it by the end user locally in a .txt or .html file and not on a server. But, that's all I'm seeing (how to save to a server). I have no server and I don't plan on making one any time soon.

Comment: http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration i think this will help you

Comment: It didn't work. It just resets everything and erases all work.

Comment: oh well worth a shot!